# Pandas select data in q quantile

Tags: pandas, numpy, quantile

I have a pandas time series `ts = pd.TimeSeries(np.random.normal(0, 1, 100))` and I want to select only the samples in the first `q-1` quantiles.

I am able to get quantiles interval with: `pd.qcut(ts, 10)` but how can I select only the samples in the first 9 quantiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `labels=False` option in the [qcut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.qcut.html) function.

```
ts = pd.DataFrame(pd.TimeSeries(np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)))
ts[1] = pd.qcut(ts[0], 10, labels=False)
ts.loc[ts[1] < 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could label your quantiles with integers, join it to the dataframe and write a boolean expression to select:

```
 quantiles = pd.qcut(ts, 10, labels=range(10))
 quantiles.name = 'quantiles'
 df = pd.DataFrame(ts).join(quantiles)
 df[df['quantiles'] < 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.TimeSeries` is deprecated. Just use `pd.Series`

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 1, 100))
ts[pd.qcut(ts, 10, labels=False) < 9]
```